# Why is this dynamic char array not getting correct inputs in C?

Tags: c

I'm experimenting with this very basic code and running into some memory problems.

I noticed that the char array is not reading the inputs correctly, probably eating up a new line input. The program worked fine for an int array but I still get a warning about de-referencing NULL pointer.

Here's the char array,

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int N, i;
    char* set;
    scanf_s("%d", &N);
    set = (char*)calloc(N, sizeof(char));
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        scanf_s("%c", (set+i), 1);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf("%c", *(set + i));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the int array,

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int N, i;
    int* set;
    scanf_s("%d", &N);
    set = (int*)calloc(N, sizeof(int));
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        scanf_s("%d", (set+i));
    }
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", *(set + i));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As mentioned earlier, the int array works perfectly fine but I still want to fix the warning.

Anyways the output for char array is just 'a' and new lines when I enter "a b c" as input and hit enter, Alternatively I tried entering just 'a' and hitting enter and it doesn't even let me input the other characters anymore.

I want to understand what exactly is wrong and want to fix it. The current IDE I'm using is VS but I'd like a gcc 6.3 compatible version as well.

Edit: The error I'm getting is on the printf line and it reads-

`Warning  C6011   Dereferencing NULL pointer 'set+i'.`

Comment: Have you tried printing the char you think you just read instead of waiting to the end and printing them all. Also: what is giving a warning about dereferencing a NULL ? You should include the full "warning".

Comment: You also neglected to include `<stdio.h>`, which is required for `printf` and `scanf` proper.

Comment: added the error code. oh and I did include <stdio.h>, looks like the copy-pasting messed up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary difference between the `int` version that works and the `char` version that doesn't is that you use `%d` and `%c` — and `%d` skips white space but `%c` does not.

Change the `"%c"` to `" %c"` and you're in with a fighting chance.

Three `scanf()` — or `scanf_s()` if you're working on Windows — conversions do not skip white space.  They are `%c`, `%[…]` (scan sets), and `%n`.